# After success full purchase coins not adding in android app

Tags: android

i have ab app where people buy coins but after the pay coins not adding in the app here is the code of the app
1 more thing why people cant buy item more than once i have enabled in google that people can buy more than once dear

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.BillingProcessor;
import com.anjlab.android.iab.v3.TransactionDetails;

public class BuyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BillingProcessor.IBillingHandler {
    private BillingProcessor bp;
    private TextView tvSubmit, tvNext;
    TextView tvCoin, tvBuy;
    private EditText etfname, etsecondname, etaddress;
    private TransactionDetails purchaseTransactionDetails = null;
    public static String MyPREFERENCES = "inapp";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_buy);
        init();
        clickListener();
    }

    private void clickListener() {
        tvNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                String url = "google.com";
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }

    private void init() {
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        sharedpreferences.getBoolean("purchase", false);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();
        etfname = findViewById(R.id.etfname);
        etsecondname = findViewById(R.id.et_secondname);
        etaddress = findViewById(R.id.et_address);
        tvSubmit = findViewById(R.id.tv_submit);
        tvCoin = findViewById(R.id.tvcoin);
        tvBuy = findViewById(R.id.tvbuy);
        tvNext = findViewById(R.id.tv_next);
        bp = new BillingProcessor(this, getResources().getString(R.string.play_console_license), this);
        bp.initialize();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProductPurchased(String productId, TransactionDetails details) {
        int coins = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
        coins = coins + 9;
        tvCoin.setText(coins);
    // store value of coins variable instead of hardcoded number
        sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", 9).apply();
        startActivity(new Intent(BuyActivity.this, ProcessingActivity.class));
        finish();
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onProductPurchased: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPurchaseHistoryRestored() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onPurchaseHistoryRestored: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingError(int errorCode, Throwable error) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingError: ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBillingInitialized() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingInitialized: ");

        String premium = getResources().getString(R.string.premium);

        purchaseTransactionDetails = bp.getSubscriptionTransactionDetails(premium);

        bp.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
        tvBuy.setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
            if (bp.isSubscriptionUpdateSupported()) {
                bp.subscribe(this, premium);
            } else {
                Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingInitialized: Subscription updated is not supported");
            }
        });
        tvSubmit.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            String fname, sname, address;
            fname = etfname.getText().toString();
            sname = etsecondname.getText().toString();
            address = etaddress.getText().toString();
           /* if (!fname.isEmpty()) {
                if (!sname.isEmpty()) {
                    if (!address.isEmpty()) {*/
            int coin = sharedpreferences.getInt("coins", 0);
            if (coin < 5) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(BuyActivity.this);
                ViewGroup viewGroup = findViewById(android.R.id.content);
                View dialogView = LayoutInflater.from(v.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.custom_alert, viewGroup, false);
                builder.setView(dialogView);
                AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
                alertDialog.show();
                dialogView.findViewById(R.id.buttonOk).setOnClickListener(v1 -> {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
                    if (bp.isSubscriptionUpdateSupported()) {
                        bp.subscribe(this, premium);
                    } else {
                        Log.d("MainActivity", "onBillingInitialized: Subscription updated is not supported");
                    }
                });
                if (sharedpreferences.getBoolean("inapp", false)) {

                } else {

                }
            }

                   /* } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Address is Empty!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Second Name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Enter First Name!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }*/

        });

       /* if (hasSubscription()) {
            tvStatus.setText("Status: Premium");
        } else {
            tvStatus.setText("Status: Free");
        }*/
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (!bp.handleActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (bp != null) {
            bp.release();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private boolean hasSubscription() {
        if (purchaseTransactionDetails != null) {
            return purchaseTransactionDetails.purchaseInfo != null;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

`

i just want to add coins in the app 1 more thing why people cant buy item more than once i have enabled in google that people can buy more than once dear

Comment: @vlad-guriev a person told me after buy that coins not showing and one more thing how to make it consume able that people can buy more dear

Comment: @vladguriev a person told me after buy that coins not showing and one more thing how to make it consume able that people can buy more dear

Answer (score 0):

To purchase a product more than once, you have to explicitly [consume](https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3#consume-purchased-products) it after the purchase have been successful and coins have been rewarded.

As for the issue that coins are not added, maybe this part of your snippet is the reason:

```
// store value of coins variable instead of hardcoded number
        sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", 9).apply();
```

You can simply replace it with `sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", coins).apply();`

Comment: when i am adding sharedpreferences.edit().putInt("coins", coins).apply(); then app getting closed while buying dear

Comment: @shvybanlin what do the error logs say?

Comment: @shvybanlin btw, the previous line, `tvCoin.setText(coins);`, doesn't work, as `.setText(int)` is an overload that accepts a resource id. You can fix it by following: `tvCoin.setText(String.valueOf(coins));`

Comment: @shvybanlin how exactly did you make sure they are not added?

Comment: a person told me after buy that coins not showing and one more thing how to make it consume able that people can buy more dear

Comment: a person told me after buy that coins not showing and one more thing how to make it consume able that people can buy more dear